# Search form and search result in same viewpage in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, search

I'm trying to create a module that has search form and search result together like following picture

[image]

In that module I have 4 dropdownlist and one text field

this is What I did upto now

This is Model Class

```
public class ProductCollectionVM
{
    public IEnumerable<ProductCollection> List_ProductCollection { get; set; }
    public ProductCollection Form_ProductCollection { get; set; }
}

public class ProductCollection
{
    public string Product_ID { get; set; }        
    public string ProductType_ID { get; set; }
    public string ProductCategory_ID { get; set; }
    // more properties
}
```

This is my cshtml view page

```
@model albaraka.Models.ProductCollectionVM
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Product_Search", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    ....
    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.ProductType_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.ProductType_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Product_TypeListEn, "Select Product Type", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.ProductType_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" }) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.Product_TypeAr, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.ProductCategory_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.ProductCategory_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.Product_CategoryListEn, "Select Product Category", new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Form_ProductCollection.ProductCategory_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

   // .... more controls

   <input type="submit" value="Search Products" class="btn btn-default" />
}

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(y => y.Form_ProductCollection.Product_ID</th>
        <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(y => y.Form_ProductCollection.ProductType_ID)</th>
        // more table headings
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.List_ProductCollection)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Product_ID)</td>
            <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductType_ID)</td>
            // .....
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

This is controller class

```
public ActionResult Product_Search([Bind(Prefix = "Form_ProductCollection")]ProductCollection _Productcollection , ProductCollection PC)
{
    Product_Type_DropDownListEn();          
    Product_Category_DropDownListEn();
    Country_DropDownList();
    Subsidary_DropDownListEn();
    var incomplete_products = (from P in db.AB_Product
                               join S in db.AB_Subsidary on P.Subsidary_ID equals S.SubsidaryID
                               where P.Status != "Active"
                               select new ProductCollection
                               {
                                   Product_ID = P.ProductID,
                                   ProductType_ID = P.ProductTypeID,
                                   ProductCategory_ID = P.ProductCategoryID,
                                   Product_Name_En = P.ProductTitleEn,
                                   Susidary_ID = P.Subsidary_ID,
                                   Country_ID = S.Country,
                                   CreatedDate = P.CreatedDate,
                                   Status = P.Status
                               }).ToList();

    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PC.ProductType_ID))
        incomplete_products = incomplete_products.Where(p => p.ProductType_ID.StartsWith(PC.ProductType_ID)).ToList();
    // .... more filtering
    return View(incomplete_products);
}
```

But once I do debug this getting following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Project_Name.Models.ProductCollection]',
>   but this dictionary requires a model item of type
>   'Project_Name.Models.ProductCollectionVM'.

Is this correct approach in my controller class , Or is there any other better way to do this in same view

Comment: You view has `@model ProductCollectionVM` so in your controller you need to return an instance of `ProductCollectionVM` (not `IEnumerable<ProductCollection>`)

Comment: how to return an instance of ProductCollectionVM ?

Comment: Initialize it, then set the `List_ProductCollection` to `incomplete_products` and return it (but you really should be using ajax for this to get better performance)

Comment: `ProductCollectionVM model = new ProductCollectionVM ();` is this how to initialize it ?

Comment: Yes, and then `model.List_ProductCollection = incomplete_products;` followed by `return View(model);`

Comment: thnks now no errors. this is updated code https://dotnetfiddle.net/MB9UFv but once I check search function seems like its wrong, also link also have wide url , how to correct this, or is this ordinary format `http://localhost:49669/Home/Product_Search?__RequestVerificationToken=OPZpHRfY--b6zGC5doJnN1I4ASMuX7UbBklwlkHo0cSCYx5b-19ypdll_0AnFuYpQ5cFAabGgJbrnDqlAvBKYzc_a8qfTlRaTqPDZXwzEbo1&Form_ProductCollection.ProductType_ID=Asset&Form_ProductCollection.ProductCategory_ID=&Form_ProductCollection.Country_ID=&Form_ProductCollection.Susidary_ID=&Form_ProductCollection.CreatedDate=`

Comment: You making a GET, so all the form controls are included as query string parameters. As I noted previously, you really should be using ajax for this. And you really should be using a view models containing only the properties you need for the view.

Comment: do I need to use @using (Ajax.BeginForm ? 
can you refer good resource to use ajax for this task ?

Comment: No, and I would not recommend it (just unnecessary extra overhead). No time now, but I'll fork your fiddle and show how you should do it (may be a few hours before I get a chance)

Comment: okay thank you very much!!

Comment: @StephenMuecke Then I try to come up with this approach https://dotnetfiddle.net/puDRME , but seems not working

Comment: Try this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/STdZy5). Obviously not complete, but I'm sure you will get the idea

Comment: @StephenMuecke you have used int datatype for my string data type variables , such as `int? type, int? category, int? country, int? subsidary` then I changed those to string again but then how controller syntax should change , like `if (type.HasValue)` ?

Comment: You just need `if(type == null)`. But why are you using `string`? You have properties `ProductTypeID`, `ProductCategoryID` etc, which suggest they are identifiers meaning they should be `int`, not `string`

Comment: is it that `if(type == null)` or `if(type != null)` ?

Comment: since my IDs can include characters and different type of symbols, I've designed like that , am I in wrong path ?

Comment: Why would you need characters and special symbols in an identifier field? Seems odd way to do it. But yes it should be `if(type != null)`

Comment: @StephenMuecke since I have multiple drop-downs (filters) I have change your fiddle to this https://dotnetfiddle.net/nKfmee, this is working perfectly for 1st drop down , but once I put second one getting error in ` @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, Model.CategoryList, "", new { @class = "form-control" })` line in cshtml view file as `DataBinding: 'albaraka.Models.AB_ProductType' does not contain a property with the name 'ProductCategoryID'.` whats wrong with my approach

Comment: There is no point creating a fiddle that uses a db context which does not exist and cant be run or tested. I have already answered the question relating to your error (see below). You need to ask a new question with (only) the relevant code and indicating which line the error is occurring on.

Comment: okay thank you very much for your assistance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view declares the model as `@model albaraka.Models.ProductCollectionVM`, but when you submit, you return the view as `IEnumerable<ProductCollection>` hence the error.

In the POST method, you need to initialize a new instance of `ProductCollectionVM` and return it

```
public ActionResult Product_Search(.....)
{
  // filter your collection
  var incomplete_products = ....
  ProductCollectionVM model = new ProductCollectionVM()
  {
    List_ProductCollection = incomplete_products;
  };
  return View(model)
}
```

However, you will get better performance by using ajax to submit the form values and return either a partial view of the table or JSON containing the table values and update the DOM in the success callback. Refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/STdZy5) for a simplified example

Answer (score 0):

In your `Controller` you return this class:

```
select new ProductCollection
```

But on your `View` you use:

```
@model albaraka.Models.ProductCollectionVM
```

You should change class in your `Controller` to `ProductCollectionVM`